# Android textview link and open webview

Tags: android, textview, android-webview

just finished hello world on android.

just want to ask:
how to make a textview as a link and connect the link to a webview page to display data?

Or is it possible to to make a textview link and after clicking the link, another textview will open?

Sorry guys, I really don't know much about android right now.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks buddy for the idea

after a couple of searching on the web. i have this code and it seems to work.

```
@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_first); // Our only layout for this app is   main.xml

    // Initialize the UI components
    changingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) { // Parameter v stands for the view that was clicked.  


    if(v.getId() == R.id.textView1){ 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Textview Link Testing!", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    // getId() returns this view's identifier.
    if(v.getId() == R.id.leftButton){
        // setText() sets the string value of the TextView
        changingTextView.setText("You clicked this button1");
    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.rightButton){
        changingTextView.setText("You clicked this button2");

        WebView page = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        String text = "<html><head>"
                  + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #ffdec2; background-color: #1F0C01;}"
                  + "</style></head>"
                  + "<body>"
                  + "<p align=\"justify\">"                
                  + getString(R.string.multistring) 
                  + "</p> "
                  + "<p align=\"justify\">" 
                  + getString(R.string.multistring1)
                  + "</p> "
                  + "</body></html>";

        page.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line should open your built-in browser, with the specified url:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
```

Your Activity should have parts like this:

```
//define class variables here
TextView tv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //some code of yours
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);
    //more code of yours
}

//whatever else you have in your source code

public void onClick(View v)
{
    //handle the click events here, in this case open www.google.com with the default browser
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
}
```

It might not be 100% accurate syntax, since I did just write this on my own, but you get the idea.